# After neo4j backup no index hit

Tags: spring, neo4j, backup, spring-data-neo4j

I´m running the community edition of neo4j (2.0.1). With spring-data-neo4j 3.1.0.RELEASE.
I have no automatic index configured in my neo4j server. spring-data-neo4j is doing the work for me.

After shutting down the neo4j service, i made a copy of the data folder and tried to replace it with the one in my local environment.

After starting the local server all the data is there. I can see the list of my index at this address: 
    `http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/`

When I try to search for something in the index the result is "No index hits".

In my backup folder the index folder is there. Is there something else to do in order to backup the whole database including indexes?

**update:**

this is my annotation for the fulltext search:

`@Indexed(indexType = FULLTEXT, indexName = "title-search", unique = false)
private String title;`

And here my implementation:

`Index<Node> title = template.getIndex("title-search", Application.class);
IndexHits<Node> nodeIndexHits = title.query("title", query);`

I´m querying the index directly and not using the repository method to avoid the label fetching for the obj mapping of SDN.

Answer (score 0):

SDN 3.1.0 should not need to create legacy indexes in your database except for fulltext indexes. It only creates and uses schema indexes by default otherwise, which it also recreates at startup if they are missing.

How do you "search for something"